# Want content centered in parent but flex wrapped

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following markup (using Bootstrap 4):

```css
.resource{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="resource">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="wrapper d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
        <div class="card col-5">
          <p>test1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-5">
            <p>test1</p>
          </div>
        <div class="card col-5">
          <p>test1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the cards to be left aligned rather than centered. I can achieve this by removing `justify-content-center` from the `.wrapper`, but then the `.wrapper` isn't centered in `.container` anymore.

How can I achieve both, making `.wrapper` centered in the `.container` and make the `.card` left aligned?

Comment: `justify-content-center` remove this from the `wrapper` and let it be inside `row` you will get your desired result

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean? Removing `justify-content-center` will not affect the position of `.wrapper` in `.container > .row`.

The wrapper is still centered, and the cards are aligned from left.

But you need to use `col-6` instead of `col-5` if you want to make a 2-columned grid, since grid system in Bootstrap is base 12 not base 10.

```css
.resource{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="resource">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <!-- removed "justify-content-center" -->
      <div class="wrapper d-flex flex-wrap">
        <!-- changed from "col-5" to "col-6" -->
        <div class="card col-6">
          <p>test1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6">
            <p>test1</p>
          </div>
        <div class="card col-6">
          <p>test1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this class only `justify-content-center`

```
<div class="resource">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="wrapper d-flex flex-wrap">
        <div class="card col-5">
          <p>test1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-5">
            <p>test1</p>
          </div>
        <div class="card col-5">
          <p>test1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```